# Add a vertical line between columns

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx

I am creating tables for the appendix of my thesis and I have the following problems with a specific table:

- My table starts on the next page. What should I change in the case I want my table to split in several pages?
- I would like to add a vertical line between the second and third column (since the information presented in column 1 and 2 are the same as the information presented in column 3 and 4).

I show you the code I used and the result of it (please see that I used already newcolumntypes for other tables in the document). The table should start after appendix B.

```
\usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{0.1\textwidth}}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}

\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\section{Suppliers´ production capabilities}
\begin{table}[ht]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Facility Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Product}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Facility Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Product}} \\
\midrule
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords & Texttexttexttexttexttexttex & Wordswordswordswordswordswords       \\
Texttexttexttexttexttextt & Wordswordswordswordswordswords        \\
 \bottomrule                                  
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{Supplier facilities´ production capabilities }
\label{tab:my-table}
\end{table}
```

[image]

I would be extremely grateful if you can assist me with this problem!

Comment: To split a table across pags, take a look at the `longtable` package. To add a vertical lines between column 2 and 3, you can use `\begin{tabular}{ll|ll}` (I added `|` and removed a `l` since you only seem to need 4 columns, but declared 5 of them) However, please be aware that horizontal lines from the booktabs package were designed to be used without vertical lines, hence there will be small gaps around the intersections if you combine them.

Comment: When using longtable instead of table, the table becomes too wide..

Comment: ... Also, please do not use `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%` in order to make sure a table its into the given textwidth. This sill result in inconsistent font sizes throughout  your document. There are better options such as manually decreasing the font size (and if needed the value of `tabcolsep`), as well as allowing linebreaks inside of table cells.

Comment: If you want to allow linebreaks inside of table cells, while at the same time ensuring your table does not exceed the textwidth and allowing it to span multiple pages, take a look at the `xltabular` package.

Comment: @MaxLombaVrouenraets - It is not the use of `longtable` *per se* that's making the material exceed `\textwidth` in width. Instead, it's the inappropriate use of the `l` column type, which doesn't allow linebreaks.

Comment: Since I mentioned `booktabs` lines being incompatible with vertical lines, you could alternatively add a larger horizontal white space between column 2 and 3 as a guide to the eye. Probably you could also combine this with two `\cmidrule` commands instead of the `\midrule` in order to add even more visual separation between the two parts.

Comment: I tried to use xltabular and I change the columntype by L and the whole layout is changed.. could you please show me the whole code?

Comment: How do you define the `L` column type? It is not a standard  column specifier.

Comment: It is in the question: newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a `longtable`-based solution. All four columns allow automatic line breaking. The column widths are equal and are calculated so as to take up the maximum available width.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=1in]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newlength\mylen
\setlength\mylen{\dimexpr0.25\textwidth-1.5\tabcolsep-0.25\arrayrulewidth\relax}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\RaggedRight}p{\mylen}}
\begin{document}

\section{Suppliers' production capabilities}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{} ZZ | ZZ @{}}

%%% headers and footers:

\caption{Supplier facilities' production capabilities }
\label{tab:my-table}\\
\hline
\textbf{Facility Name} & \textbf{Product} & 
\textbf{Facility Name} & \textbf{Product} \\
\hline
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{4}{@{}l}{Table \thetable, cont'd}\\[1ex]
\hline
\textbf{Facility Name} & \textbf{Product} & 
\textbf{Facility Name} & \textbf{Product} \\
\hline
\endhead

\hline
\multicolumn{4}{r@{}}{\footnotesize cont'd on following page}\\
\endfoot

\hline
\endlastfoot

%%% Body of table

Texttext texttextt exttexttex exttexttex & Wordswordswords wordswordswords & Texttext texttextt exttexttex exttexttex & Wordswordswords wordswordswords \\
Texttext texttextt exttextt & Wordswordswords wordswordswords & Texttext texttextt exttexttex exttexttex & Wordswordswords wordswordswords \\
Texttext texttextt exttextt & Wordswordswords wordswordswords & Texttext texttextt exttexttex exttexttex & Wordswordswords wordswordswords \\
Texttext texttextt exttextt & Wordswordswords wordswordswords & Texttext texttextt exttexttex exttexttex & Wordswordswords wordswordswords \\
Texttext texttextt exttextt & Wordswordswords wordswordswords & Texttext texttextt exttexttex exttexttex & Wordswordswords wordswordswords \\
Texttext texttextt exttextt & Wordswordswords wordswordswords & Texttext texttextt exttexttex exttexttex & Wordswordswords wordswordswords \\
Texttext texttextt exttextt & Wordswordswords wordswordswords & Texttext texttextt exttexttex exttexttex & Wordswordswords wordswordswords \\
Texttext texttextt exttextt & Wordswordswords wordswordswords & Texttext texttextt exttexttex exttexttex & Wordswordswords wordswordswords \\
Texttext texttextt exttextt & Wordswordswords wordswordswords & Texttext texttextt exttexttex exttexttex & Wordswordswords wordswordswords \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to use `xltabular` – it's the same syntax as for longtable, except you declare the total width. In particular, in a longtable, you don't use the `table` environment (it is not a float), the caption is incorporated to the table, in the *firsthead* section.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\hspace{0pt}}p{0.1\textwidth}}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}


\begin{document}

\section{Suppliers´ production capabilities}
\lipsum[1-3]

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{*{4}{L}}
\caption{Supplier facilities´ production capabilities }
\label{tab:my-table} \\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Facility Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Product}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Facility Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Product}} \\
\midrule
\endfirsthead
{\footnotesize (Continued)}\\
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Facility Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Product}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Facility Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Product}} \\
\midrule
\endhead
\midrule
\multicolumn{4}{r}{\footnotesize (to be continued)}
\endfoot
\bottomrule
\endlastfoot
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words & Text text text text text text tex & Words words words words words words \\ \addlinespace
Text text text text text textt & Words words words words words words \
\end{xltabular}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. However, Overleaf does not recompile when I install the package xltabular. Have you experienced something similar? Could I substitute xltabular by longtable?

Comment: I don't use Overleaf, unfortunately. Strange that Overleaf doesn't have xltabular. Probably because it's not a very old package. You can substitute by long table, but have to define the `L` column type as `p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}`.

Comment: It does not want to work.. my whole table appears centered, with the headers one above each other. I defined M instead of L, since I use L for other tables: \newcolumntype{M}{p{\dimexpr 0.25\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}. Then, I used your code but I use the following expression: \begin{longtable}{\textwidth}{*{4}{M}}

Comment: Don't use the `{\textwidth}` argument with longtable! Precribing the overall width of the table works with `tabularx` & friends, and with `table*`.